# Reduce function returns wrong logical output when using is.na inside the input function

Tags: r

Compare the results of the following evaluations:

```
Reduce(function (x, y) is.na(x) | is.na(y), list(c(1, 2, NA), 1:3, 1:3))
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

&

```
Reduce(function (x, y) x | y, lapply(list(c(1, 2, NA), 1:3, 1:3), is.na))
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

They are logically doing the same calculation but yields different results. The second result is what I am expecting. Why did it behaves as the first example shows?

---

And, by the way, when the list contains only two logical vectors:

```
Reduce(function (x, y) is.na(x) | is.na(y), list(c(1, 2, NA), 1:3))
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

`Reduce` behaves as expected again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at it with `accumulate=TRUE`:

```r
Reduce(function (x, y) is.na(x) | is.na(y), list(c(1, 2, NA), 1:3, 1:3), accumulate=T)
# [[1]]
# [1]  1  2 NA
# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [[3]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

We start with the first vector, `c(1, 2, NA)`.

1. On the first iteration of the function, `x` is `c(1,2,NA)` and `y` is `1:3`. The return value is `c(F,F,TRUE)`.
2. On the second iteration of the function, `x` is the return value from the previous step, so `c(F,F,TRUE)`; and `y` is the next vector, `1:3`. Note that none of `x` is `NA`, so therefore `is.na(x)` is all false, as is `is.na(y)`. Therefore, the output from this step is `c(F,F,F)`.
3. On the third iteration, similar to the second, `x` is the output from the previous step (`c(F,F,F)`). Nothing is `NA`.

I think what you need is

```r
Reduce(function (x, y) x | is.na(y), list(c(1, 2, NA), 1:3, 1:3), init = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Notes about this:

- First thing is to consider what you want "passed" between iterations of the function as the first argument `x`. In your case, you *need* it to be logical, but you actually pass a mix (numeric the first time, logical the second and subsequent). Think of what is passed between iterations as the "state of the system".
- The "identity" (starting-point) for your logic is all-false, or `init=c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)`.
- From there, note that the first argument should always be logical and never `NA`, so we change the first part of your conditional from `is.na(x)` to `x`. If you are somewhat paranoid about the data going into this, you can always do

  ```r
  Reduce(function (x, y) (is.na(x) | x) | is.na(y), list(c(1, 2, NA), 1:3, 1:3),
         init = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
  ```

  where we have really replaced your original `is.na(x)` with `(is.na(x) | x)`. (The grouping parens are not required, just added for visualizing it here.)

Comment: Aha yes, I see where my silly fault comes from. My mind have been twisted. Thank you!

Comment: Comparing to your suggestions, ```Reduce("|", lapply(list(c(1, 2, NA), 1:3, 1:3), is.na))``` is simpler. Would you suggest me to switch to yours in future practice?

Comment: No, actually that is (imho) more readable. Glad you got the gist of the mistake :-)